# JFreechart tick units

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using the following code which i got off the web

```
TickUnits units = new TickUnits();
DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("$0");
DecimalFormat df2 = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");

// we can add the units in any order, the TickUnits collection will
// sort them...
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(100, df1, 0));
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(50, df1, 0));
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(20, df1, 0));
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(10, df1, 0));
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(5, df1, 0));
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(2, df1, 0));
units.add(new NumberTickUnit(1, df1, 0));
```

As I am very new, I don't understand what this piece of code actually does. I Thought that it sets the values on the *y* axis, but that does not seem to be the case as there are values exceeding 100 dollars on the *y* axis. What exactly does this piece of code do. (Also what exactly is tick units. Does it define the labels on the axes or am I mistaken here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `TickUnits` define the format of `Axis` labels, but a complete explication is beyond the scope of Stackoverflow. The [developer guide](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/devguide.html)<sup>†</sup> is dispositive, but it may prove instructive to examine the methods that return a `TickUnitSource` for a particular `Axis` subclass. For example, the source code for [`createIntegerTickUnits()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/a362a41d4d944f6be5d3ec2f93c32bc975e10c0b/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.java#L681) in `NumberAxis`, along with [`NumberTickUnitSource`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberTickUnitSource.java)

The example cited is flawed in that it ignores the user's locale.

Addendum: If you want localized currency format, override the default `Number` formatter.

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
NumberAxis range = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
range.setNumberFormatOverride(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance());
```

<sup>†</sup><sub>*Disclaimer: Not affiliated with Object Refinery Limited; just a satisfied customer and very minor contributor.*</sub>

Comment: If it defines the values on the axis why do i observe values beyond this range.

Comment: A `ValueAxis` uses its `TickUnitSource` to auto-range labels, but you can override this using `setRange()`. Adding more `NumberTickUnit` instances changes the granularity; the bounds are determined by the `Dataset`.

Comment: I am creating my own tickuits as mentioned in the program above. I have used the setRange too from 20 to 70. This still does not prevent values beyond 70 to show up.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question to clarify your requirements and to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your findings.

Comment: I finally got it. I had to add setLimitAble(true) before using setLimitRange(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Neither is present in [r1941](http://jfreechart.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jfreechart/trunk/source/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.java?revision=1941&view=markup). What version are you using?

Comment: afreechart which is based on jfreechart (android based) most of the functions are the same though one or two may be different