# RegularTimePeriod creation or convertion in java

Tags: java, jfreechart

I  want to create a RegularTimePeriod object with hour,min,seconds i have,how to do this i googled and got http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/RegularTimePeriod.html but i dont seem to understand what RegularTimePeriod contain create one.

in short lets say i have 02:33:54 i have broken it into h=02,m=33,s=54   now can i create a regulartimeperiod object with h,m,s?if so how

if not which object can pass to TimeSeries in jfreechart to get hh:mm:ss format along x-axis

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the date format. Related examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028000/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513).

```
axis.setDateFormatOverride(DateFormat.getTimeInstance());
```

Comment: trashgod Thanks i didnt not understand ur solution is for RegularTimeperiod or "if not which....." part i will try googling

Comment: You are welcome, but I'm not sure I understand. A `DateAxis` displays "milliseconds from the Java [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29)." The `setDateFormatOverride()` method merely supplies the format. Think of the chart as a _view_ and the data set as a _model_, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).  Try changing the format to `getTimeInstance()` in the second [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12481509/230513) to see the effect.

Comment: If you have no date information, i.e. all times are relative to `00:00:00`, you can set the time zone of the formatter to `GMT`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2705674/230513).